# Issues getting clearInterval to actually clear

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm trying to create a fading slideshow that is activated on a jQuery hover event.
My code is like this:

```
var myObj = null;
$('selector').hover(function() {
   // Code to retrieve the image URLs via ajax and construct the slideshow html 
   myObj = setInterval(playMe, 3000);
}, function() {
   clearInterval(myObj);
   myObj = null;
})

var playMe = function() {
   // this just changes the class of each images container, which changes the 
   // opacity from 0 to 1. The fade animation is done using css3 and a transition
}
```

The problem I'm getting is that the clearInterval does not always clear, especially if you're moving the cursor rapidly around the screen, thus triggering rapid mouseover/mouseout events. This then screws up the timings because I suspect there are multiple playMe's running.

Is there anyway round this? A way to actually make sure there is only ever one playMe/setInterval running?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you still have this problem if you remove the fade animation?

Comment: You are missing the closing bracket after the second handler of `$.hover`. I'm not sure if that's the issue though. Can you create a [mcve] please?

Comment: You could avoid the problem entirely and make the opacity animation perform better if you use CSS for this.

Comment: @James - Yes I do still have the issue if I remove the animation object.

Comment: @Nisarg - You are quite right. That was just a typo and is correct in the actual code.

Comment: @Rory - I am using css to do that actual animation. The playMe just add/remove a class to the respective div. IE. With out class opacity: 0; with class opacity: 1.

Comment: You can achieve this using pure CSS. Set the default state of the element (background colour etc.) and then, using the :hover pseudo-selector, re-set the properties you wish to change. Using a CSS transition, you could make it fade from one colour to another.

Comment: @Strontium_99 in that case, get rid of the `hover()` handler and interval as that's the root of your problem. Just use the `:hover` selector in CSS to start the animation and make it repeat infinitely. If you want more specific help with how to code this, please add a more complete sample to the question including your current HTML and CSS

Comment: Ok. It's a little more complex than that. The hover() event, as well as constructing the slideshow html, it also runs an ajax function that retrieves the image URLs from a database. Hence the reason I can't just use a CSS driven option.

Comment: If you somehow got the mouseenter trigger to happen twice with no mouseleave trigger between, you’d lose your reference to the “first” myObj and wouldn’t be able to clear the interval.

Comment: @James - I think you're spot on. This is what I suspect is happening. Just wonder if there is a way to somehow totally destroy the myObj, or to make sure there is only ever one myObj running?

Comment: Any chance you are applying this code to nested elements?  (like say a button and also its parent div)

Comment: No. Like I say, the problem seems to occur if I move the cursor rapidly over the selectors that should trigger the event. It's like it sometimes misses the mouseout event, and triggers another setInterval without clearing the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `myObj` is `null` before assigning a `setInterval` to it. This way, only one `setInterval` can ever be running.

```js
$(function(){
var myObj = null;
$('div#fadeinout').hover(function() {
   // Code to retrieve the image URLs via ajax and construct the slideshow html 
   if(myObj===null){
   myObj = setInterval(playMe, 3000);
   }
}, function() {
   if(myObj){
   clearInterval(myObj);
   myObj = null;
   }
})

var playMe = function() {
   // this just changes the class of each images container, which changes the 
   $('div#fadeinout').toggleClass('fade');
   // opacity from 0 to 1. The fade animation is done using css3 and a transition
}
});
```

```css
div#fadeinout{
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  transition: opacity 1.5s;
}
.fade{
  opacity: 0.25;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fadeinout">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one. Spent so long looking at the problem I forgot to use some basic logic. Big thanks.

Comment: @Strontium_99 No problem.